# Can't delete default Google My Business website after adding custom domain

Tags: google-my-business

I am running a Google my business (GMB) website. When starting my business, I created a website on the default domain name, `.business.site`. Some time later, I purchased a custom `.com` domain from Google Domains and added it to the business.

Until then Google search indexed the content of the business site. Now after connecting this new domain, I am trying to delete the default business site to avoid duplicate content issues. The site URL is shown in this screenshot -

[image: Best Restaurant in Bhopal - Tabbar House old site]

I can't find any option or tool to delete this website. I contacted Google team to remove the site but they did not give me an appropriate reply. After spending all my energy trying to delete the site, I am not having any success. Please suggest how I can get rid of this obnoxious issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following [Google's instructions for unpublishing Business Profile websites](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7032839):

1. Go to your Business Profile.
2. Select Edit profile and then Business information.
3. Near the top, select the Contact tab.
4. Next to "Website," select the pencil icon.
5. Select Manage.
6. On the page that opens: To unpublish: In the left panel, select More Settings and then Unpublish website.

Comment: Tried this several times but the business site reappears.

Comment: Ultimately, written in feedback and got the page removed from Google search results.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to delete default Google my Business website:**

- Log into your Google My Business account and go to the Info tab.
- Inside the Website section, remove the link to the old .business.site website. This will disconnect it from your GMB listing.
- In Google Search Console, remove the old website property. This will stop Google from crawling and indexing pages from that domain.
- If you have access, log into the hosting account for the old website and delete all the files. This will make the site inaccessible.
- You can also add a robots.txt file to the root of the old domain that disallows all crawling. The file should have this content:

> User-agent:*
> Disallow: /

- Submit a URL removal request in Google Search Console for the old domain. Ask Google not to display it in search results.
- Redirect the old domain to your new .com website or to a blank page. This will send signals that the old domain no longer has relevant content.

It can take some time for Google to update its index after you make these changes.